# Creating DEM from topography map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, dem, topography

For my geology diploma project I need to create  DEM from topography map my professor gave me to use as a base map. The map is georeferenced. My idea was to draw lines over the izolines of the map, then specify thair elevation and then create DEM. Equidistance of the izolines is 10m. I don't know how to do it or is it even possible in QGIS.

Comment: are your contours actual data or an image of an old map? are you asking how to trace the contours or how to convert contours to a DEM?

Comment: My contours are image of an old map, I want to trace contours over the izolines of the old map. After i do that I think I can make DEM using those contours. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in QGIS.  It's called digitising when you're drawing over a scanned map (image, or raster in GIS terminology).

Check this handy, simple yet accurate tutorial [Digitizing Map Data](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/digitizing_basics.html) and come back if you run into more questions.